# Batch set sock proxies in firefox

Tags: firefox, batch-file, proxy, batch-processing

I have a csv file containing a list of sock proxies. I have 50 firefox profiles and I want a way to batch set the sock proxies of all the firefox profiles by reading the csv file. So for example my firefox profiles are named:
profile1, profile2, profile3. profile1 would use line1 in csv, profile2 would use line2 in csv, profile3 would use line3 in csv and so on.

Anyway to do this in windows server 2012 R2?

Comment: Yes.  Which part are you having trouble with?  Looping through the CSV file?  Looping through the Firefox profiles?  Modifying the Firefox prefs.js?  It's easy to get overwhelmed when you're starting a project.  But if you concentrate on one thing and teach yourself how to do it, then learn the next thing, then the next, you'll accomplish great things.

Comment: I'm not a programmer so I don't know what method to use